# Race condition in line of Python

Tags: python, markov

I have an interesting problem. I am -- for shits and giggles -- trying to write a program really shortly. I have it down to 2 lines, but it has a race condition, and I can't figure out why. Here's the gist of it:

```
imports...
...[setattr(__main__, 'f', [1, 2, ..]), reduce(...random.choice(f)...)][1]...
```

**Every once in a while, the following exception will be generated. But NOT always. That's my problem.** I suspect that the order of execution is not guaranteed especially since I'm using the list trick -- I would assume that maybe the interpreter can predict that setattr() returns None and knows that I'm only selecting the 2nd thing in the list, so it defers the actual setattr() to later. But it only happens sometimes. Any ideas? Does CPython automatically thread some things like map, filter, reduce calls?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(" ".join([setattr(n,'f',open(sys.argv[1],"r").read().replace("\n"," ").split(" ")),setattr(n,'m',c.defaultdict(list)),g.reduce(lambda p,e:p+[r.choice(m[p[-1]])],range(int(sys.argv[2])),[r.choice(list(filter(lambda x:[m[x[0]].append(x[1]),x[0].isupper()][1],zip(f[:-1],f[1:]))))[0]])][2]))
  File "test4.py", line 2, in <lambda>
    print(" ".join([setattr(n,'f',open(sys.argv[1],"r").read().replace("\n"," ").split(" ")),setattr(n,'m',c.defaultdict(list)),g.reduce(lambda p,e:p+[r.choice(m[p[-1]])],range(int(sys.argv[2])),[r.choice(list(filter(lambda x:[m[x[0]].append(x[1]),x[0].isupper()][1],zip(f[:-1],f[1:]))))[0]])][2]))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

I've tried modifying globals() and vars() insetad of using setattr(), but that does not seem to help (same exception sequence).

Here's the actual code:

```
import sys,collections as c,random as r,functools as g,__main__ as n
print(" ".join([setattr(n,'f',open(sys.argv[1],"r").read().replace("\n"," ").split(" ")),setattr(n,'m',c.defaultdict(list)),g.reduce(lambda p,e:p+[r.choice(m[p[-1]])],range(int(sys.argv[2])),[r.choice(list(filter(lambda x:[m[x[0]].append(x[1]),x[0].isupper()][1],zip(f[:-1],f[1:]))))[0]])][2]))
```

If you're curious: This is to read in a text file, generate a Markov model, and spit out a sentence.

Comment: "it is nondeterministic, and I can't figure out why...`random.choice`"

Comment: Yes -- it's a random.choice selecting from a sequence that should not be empty if 'f' has been assigned a value.

Comment: Is it really necessary to do it all in one long line of code?

Comment: @Barmar Not at all. Just curious about this.

Comment: Don't write confusing code on purpose, then ask volunteers for help when it doesn't work.

Comment: @KSFT Clarified the first example to show my problem more clearly.

Comment: Okay: Clarification: sometimes I get the exception, sometimes I don't. That's the nondeterminism I'm tryingto figure out, not the random.choice part.

Comment: You're using `random.choice()`. It's obviously going to be nondeterministic.

Comment: You're making it additionally hard for us to understand the code with your one-letter abbreviations for the functions.

Comment: Have you tried writing a non-golfed form of your program and debugging that?

Comment: I would be quite startled if it turned out you were actually encountering nondeterminism unrelated to random.choice(), or race conditions in the absence of explicit threading. Show us all the code, or solve it yourself.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Please re-read the question -- I changed nondeterminisim to race condition.

Comment: There's no automatic multi-threading. Everything is done in order, according to operator precedence and associativity rules (generally left-to-right).

Comment: What makes you think it's a _race_ condition?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I was indeed wrong. Not a race condition. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's what actually happened: In my sentence generation, I sometimes hit the last word in the file (which in some cases, depending on the file, does not have a possible successor state). Hence, I'm trying to choose from an empty list in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
random.choice()
```

Well, of course that is nondeterministic. If you are very careful, you could set the seed of the pseudo-random number generator to something constant, and hope that's fabricates the same sequence every time. There's a good chance it will work.

```
random.seed(42); ...
```

Comment: I'm not saying that. I'm saying I sometimes get the exception, sometimes I don't.

Comment: he's not saying that the values are nondeterministic, he's claiming that the order of operations is nondeterministic, and that's causing errors sometimes.

Comment: @hugelgupf: You *are* saying that. You have said entirely the wrong thing in your question, and you should say something else.

Comment: @hugelgupf, why? it's nothing to do with race conditions.